# How to access to a protected function with the overloading of the operator << ? C++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

For a exercise in C++, I must to use a protected c++ in a function which overload the operator <<.

But we know that protected function is accessible in a class or with the keyword friend if we want to define the function in a cpp file.

For the moment, I have one abstract class and the main.

I dont't have any idea how I can to fix this error, and I wanted to finish as far as possible this exercice early ;)

#### Card.hpp

```
#ifndef CARD_HPP
#define CARD_HPP

#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class Card
{
    std::string name;

    protected:
        virtual std::ostream & toStream(std::ostream & out){out << name;return out;}

    public:
        Card(std::string n):name(n){}
        friend std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & out, const Card  &c);        

};

#endif
```

#### Card.cpp

```
#include <Card.hpp>

std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & out, const Card  &c)
{
    return c.toStream(out);
}
```

#### main.cpp

```
#include <Card.hpp>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Card card("montain");
    cout << card << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

#### Output

```
clang++ -Wall -std=c++14 -c -o obj/main.o src/main.cpp -I include
clang++ -Wall -std=c++14 -c -o obj/Card.o src/Card.cpp -I include
src/Card.cpp:5:12: error: member function 'toStream' not viable: 'this' argument has type 'const Card', but function is not
      marked const
    return c.toStream(out);
           ^
include/Card.hpp:12:32: note: 'toStream' declared here
        virtual std::ostream & toStream(std::ostream & out){out << name;return out;}
                               ^
1 error generated.
makefile:16: recipe for target 'obj/Card.o' failed
make: *** [obj/Card.o] Error 1
```

#### The makefile

```
CC = clang++
CFLAGS = -Wall -std=c++14
HDIR = include

ABSTRACT = obj/Card.o

.PHONY: doc

compile: bin/main
    ./bin/main

bin/main: obj/main.o ${ABSTRACT}
    ${CC} ${CFLAGS} -o $@ $^

obj/%.o: src/%.cpp
    ${CC} ${CFLAGS} -c -o $@ $< -I ${HDIR}

doc:
    doxygen Doxyfile

clean: 
    rm obj/*.o
    rm bin/*

cleanDoc:
    rm doc/* -rf
```

Comment: Here I have just one class in my project, which is the class "Card".
So I not have need of make a inheritance for the moment

Comment: Ok @Hari_Sheldon, you have just confirm what I have undestood ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not that the function is protected, but that it is not `const`.

> ```
> src/Card.cpp:5:12: error: member function 'toStream' not viable: 'this' argument has type 'const Card', but function is not
>   marked const
> return c.toStream(out);
> ```

As the error message says, `c` is `const` due to `const Card  &c`, and as of that you can only call const member functions on `c`.

So either make your `toStream` member function `const`:

```
virtual std::ostream & toStream(std::ostream & out) const
```

Or change the streaming operator so that `c` is not const. But that's not recommended, you should only pass as non const ref if the function is expected to change/replace the passed argument:

```
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & out, Card  &c)
```

Comment: How ok ! When I add the keyword const before a class and I use a function with this class, I must add the keyword const at this function ?

Comment: A member function that is **not** marked as `const` could change the object members, but with `const Card  &c` you say that `c` is `const` and must not change, and due to that you can only do actions on it that guarantee that the object does not change, and a member function that is not `const` does not guarantee that.

Comment: Ok, I undestood, thank you for your help and your explanation ^^

Comment: I would NOT change the `operator<<()` to make the second argument, `c`, not `const`.    Generally speaking, an output operator that is allowed to change the object being output is highly suspicious.